# ice:inputTextarea in IE is not resizable

Tags: css, icefaces

I have a text area. In Chrome and Mozilla I don't have any problems. The behaviour is exactly the way I want. The problem is with the IE. I want the "box" to be resizable and if the user enter 500 characters to be able to increase the height/width of the box.
Do you have any ideas how I can make it work in IE? [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45fsd.png)

Answer (score 0):

IceFaces is setting the `resize: both;` css attribute to indicate to the browser that the area should be resizable. IE is simply ignoring this attribute.

Apart from utilizing JQuery you may want to have a look at the `<ace:resizable>` component in later IceFaces implementations (Available from IceFaces 3.0 onwards).

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this option, but the problem is that the project on which I'm working on is with 1.8 icefaces... . I tried with JQuery and it worked, but then I had a problem connected with the popups( they were not shown at all).